# How do i declare a variable global so that it persists? Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

This is my code

```
 on button873_(sender)
    set thePath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Please choose a folder to Hide")
    set otterthan to "chflags hidden "& thePath
do shell script otterthan
end

on button874_(sender)
    set otterthando to "chflags nohidden "& thePath
    do shell script otterthando
    end
```

But it tells me that the path is not defined, the thing i want to do is make the script remember thePath so i can use it after end.

Comment: please consider posting the actual error message, with line numbers

Answer (score 3):

The path is defined but you're using a local variable (if not defined globally somewhere else globally or as a property). Anyway looking at the way you named the handlers you're using AppleScriptObjC. AppleScriptObjC makes use of script objects which can have properties that can be used in all handlers within that script object.

```
-- AppleScriptObjC using AppleScript 2.3 syntax
script theObject
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    property thePath : missing value

    on button873:sender
        set thePath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Please choose a folder to Hide")
        set otterthan to "chflags hidden " & thePath
        do shell script otterthan
    end button873:

    on button874:sender
        set otterthando to "chflags nohidden " & thePath
        do shell script otterthando
    end button874:
end script
```

Comment: Could not connect the action button873: to target of class AppDelegate

Comment: You need to convert the syntax to and older version of AppleScript. on button873_(sender)